# Select on Impala table from NodeJs and Kerberos Authentication

Tags: node.js, kerberos, impala

i am working in a new project where i have a node server that needs to execute a select in a impala table, i am having problem because my cloudera cluster requires a kerberos authentication to execute the select.
I've search for some packages that allows to run impala queries but i can't find anyone that makes kerberos authentication.

It is possible to run selects at impala with this kind of authentication? If is possible, how can i make it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pls make sure Kerberos is installed and setup properly in server. Then you can use this URL to connect to a Impala server with Kerberos enabled,
but without SSL enabled:

```
jdbc:impala://node1.abc.com:21050;AuthMech=1;
KrbRealm=abc.com;KrbHostFQDN=node1.abc.com;
KrbServiceName=impala
```

In this example, Kerberos is enabled for JDBC connections, the Kerberos service principal name is impala/node1.abc.com@abc.com, the host name for the data source is
node1.abc.com, and the server is listening on port 21050 for JDBC connections.
You can go through this document from cloudera.
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-jdbc/latest/Cloudera-JDBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf

Comment: I see this answer is from some time ago, but I have come up against the same problem - I can't find a method to connect to an impala server (protected by kerberos) from nodejs. Please could you add some complete code sample for a connection including libraries used? Many thanks